# Getting String Index Out of Range When Inserting to Postgresql table

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm new to python, programming in general, and trying to read a .dat file and insert the data into a postgres table.

I'm getting an error and I've googled but could not come up with a resolution. Hoping someone can point me to the right direction.

Ratings table:

```
UserID int
MovieID int
Rating float
```

Ratings.dat:

```
1::122::5::838985046

1::185::5::838983525
```

Below is my code:

```
import psycopg2


ratingsfile = open('ml-10M100K/ratings.dat', 'r')
for line in ratingsfile:
    items = line.split('::')
    for values in items:
    curr.execute("INSERT INTO Ratings(UserID, MovieID, Rating)
      VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", values) 

conn.commit()
ratingsfile.close()
```

Error:

```
curr.execute("INSERT INTO Ratings(UserID, MovieID, Rating)
VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", values) 

IndexError: string index out of range
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to iterate through `items`. Instead you can assign the 3 `%s` variables as `items[index]` as follows:

```
import psycopg2


ratingsfile = open('ml-10M100K/ratings.dat', 'r')
for line in ratingsfile:
    items = line.split('::')
    curr.execute("INSERT INTO Ratings(UserID, MovieID, Rating) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)" % (items[0], items[1], items[2]))

conn.commit()
ratingsfile.close()
```

This assumes that, for example in your example Ratings.dat, that UserID is 1 (`items[0]`), MovieID is 122 and 185 (`items[1]`), and Rating is 5 (`items[2]`). The 9 digit integers at the end of each row can be accessed with `items[3]`

Comment: Yup, that does it! Thank you!